# Flickering of UX in MUI card view listing users in react using MUI Card

Tags: user-interface, material-ui, card

I have created a Card View for listing all users in the database. As I hover over Card or between cards it starts flickering between them and change the rest of all cards alignment.

```
       return(
            <Cards key={user_data.id} cardMode={props.mode}
                name={firstname + " " + lastname}
                title={designation}
                empid={user_data.emp_no}
                logo={profilephoto}
                
                email={email}
                mobile={mobile}
            />)})
```

Comment: Please add more of your code or create a codesandbox where the issue is reproducable. The sample code can't say enough to understand what the issue might be. Thanks

Comment: first of all thank u --- i found the answer as I change the CSS styles by giving max and min height and width of the card and box sizing as border-box `<Card className='card_component'
                    sx={{ minWidth: '280px', maxWidth: '282px', maxHeight:'220px',minHeight:'220px'  ,boxSizing: 'border-box' .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just search many answer, I found the maxHeight and minHeight and same in width for the card component  with boxSizing as border-box so the flicker between cards stopped..

```
<Card className='card_component'
      sx={{ minWidth: '280px',
       maxWidth: '282px', 
       maxHeight:'220px',
       minHeight:'220px'  ,
       boxSizing:'border-box', ........}}>
```